# SFTP Automatic Login

Tags: ssh, sftp

I want to know how can I connect automatically using sftp with a password as an argument in the same command to get the automatic login an execute once.

Example:

I want to put it into a script, and try to make one sentence to do this task.

Cheers,

Comment: Is using a password essential, or would an authorized key be acceptable?

Comment: Could be both, but, for security reasons, it needed a custom password.

Comment: if you are hard coding a password anywhere, the security goes out the window. Hence I believe it is your duty to convince peole who are hell bent on security to abandon using of passwords and handle authentication using authorized key pairs.

Comment: The thing, that I need to transfer many files to a remote server, but, I dnt like to that server contains my public_rsa_key, so, I need to run sometimes the script file, and inside it I need to passing the password like as argument or file way to evoid to type it any time that I will use it.

Comment: Why would it be a problem that the *public* key is stored on another system? It's not as if it can be misused.

Comment: incorrect, As others have stated you can place your settings in a file.
The Password once you connected is stored on the Machine, But is encypted. 
You then create a simple Alias if you like and you can connect.

Ill post a answer as formatting is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's four ways to do passwordless ssh/scp:

1. Create a new pass-phrase-free ssh key on the client, and add it to `authorized_keys` on the server.
2. As above, but set a passphrase on the key, and use `ssh-agent` to unlock it in advance of running scp.
3. Use ssh connection sharing, perhaps with an appropriate `ControlPersist` setting, to log into the server in advance of your scp running. The scp will reuse the same connection and not need a password.
4. Use some dodgy script to enter the password, but ssh/scp actively discourage this so it's not as easy as you'd like.

I strongly suggest you investigate the first two options (option 2 being more secure), and option 3 if authorized_keys are not available. There are plenty of places documenting how to do it.

Option 4 is possible (I see someone else has already posted a solution), but you need to be aware that that will leak your password to other users of the machine and/or anybody who can read your script. The ssh keys are protected from all but the root user, and pass-phrase protected keys are protected even from root (ssh-agent hacks aside).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SSHPASS](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)

`sshpass -p <password> sftp user@host`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

then

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
```

Now edit config to look something like:

```
# host-specific options
Host enigma
    HostName mydomain.com
    Port 2547
    ServerAliveInterval 120
User YOURUSERNAME
    TCPKeepAlive Yes
```

Now connect

```
ssh-copy-id username@server.com
```

You should be able to connect to the Server using the Hostname in the config file. 
i.e. `ssh enigma`

I have about 20 connections in my Config file, and all short referenced so i dont have to type the domain and password each time.

The secuirty flaw to this, is that all SSH connections unless you start creating different Hostfiles. Are in one file. 
Protected by one password. 
So if you store 20 Connections to the one file, Then if that one password is compromised then so are all 20 connections.

I use a couple of hosts file, Personal, Work and Misc 
its not too much of a issue if a password is leaked then